# running a server in tmux with ansible

Tags: ansible, tmux, subshell

trying to setup a staging server for an API which I'm building using Django - and so far I was cutting corners, starting the thing using `python manage.py runserver`. But now that the setup grew a bit more complex, I decided to build an ansible playbok. Everything worked fine until I got to launching gunicorn - because I want it to run inside a tmux session. Manual process doesn't seem to trivially translate to ansible. I've been manually creating tmux session:

tmux new-session -A -s api

and then running gunicorn inside this new "environment" (subshell?)

The thing is (as is probably obvious to ansible veterans), when I get to running the first step, my playbook just hangs, and never gets to the next step, which is where gunicorn is to be started. I suppose this is because I'm starting a new shell with tmux, and ansible is lost, not hearing back (because, my guess, it's still waiting for a response on the original shell? which will never come). Is there a right way to execute the "tmux" step, letting ansible use it as a context/environment for the next step, or should I just be content with ansible doing the setup, and do the tmux thing manually? I had a similar problem, when dealing with the fact that gunicorn is inside a virtualenv, but the workaround is to use a full path, which includes the virtualenv guts. Not sure if there's a similar workaround with tmux...

thanks y'all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tmux` immediately attaches to the new session, and doesn't exit until you detach from the session or the last process in the session ends. Until `tmux` exits, the rest of your script hangs.

You can use the `-D` option to prevent attaching to the session, whether or not it needs to be created.

```
tmux new-session -AD -s api
```

The rest of your script can now proceed.

---

`tmux new-session -AD -s api` is a shortcut for

```
tmux has-session -t api || tmux new-session -d -s api
```

Comment: I see; I was using tmux to make sure the process stays alive when I disconnect; can I run the process (gunicorn) without attaching to the subshell?

Comment: Yes. When you create a new session, it runs some command in the (only) pane in its (only) window. By default, that's a shell. But you can specify a different command, for example `tmux new-session -AD -s api gunicorn`. You can also interact with a detached session before attaching to it. For example, `tmux new-session -AD -s api -d gunicorn` starts `gunicorn` in window 1, and `tmux new-window -t api vim` starts up a vim editor in a new window.

Comment: /sigh -AD doesn't work (ansible hanging as before); -Ad _does_ work, but leaves me in a strange place... the process (gunicorn) _is_ running, but if I drop into the box, tmux lstells me off - no sessions, not even a server is running... the process which _is_ running my gunicorn has tmux command with all the params I provided, but the session is nowhere to be found...

Comment: interestingly enough, turns out that the "shortcut" above is not a shortcut; running the full commands you gave after it does actually work, and produces the same result as -Ad mentioned already

Comment: Update your question to show exactly how you are using Ansible to start the `tmux` session. Your version of `tmux` may also be relevant.

Comment: ugh, sorry for spamming y'all; I ended up creating another question to deal with a different angle of this same problem. it has the missing parts: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68925949/running-server-in-tmux-through-ansible