# running server in tmux through ansible

Tags: ansible, tmux, subshell

(forgive me for spamming, I should have adjusted the [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68912548/running-a-server-in-tmux-with-ansible), but it felt like I ran into a new hurdle when solving the problem)

I set a goal of running a web server with ansible: figured I'd sit it inside a tmux session. I quickly ran into ansible play hanging forever due to tmux dropping into it's own shell, but with community's help got halfway to the goal. I *can* run my server, but there's no tmux session to be found on the box.

the playbook's task is this:

```
tasks:
    - name: drop into tmux and run gunicorn
      shell:
        cmd: tmux has-session -t api || tmux new-session -d -s api /home/akarpov/.local/share/virtualenvs/htmshop_parent-NXHiij2E/bin/gunicorn backend.wsgi:application -b 127.0.0.1:4000
        chdir: htmshop_parent
```

, basically, if the session 'api' doesn't exist, launch a gunicorn (from a virtualenv) within a session, and detach.

the play reported certain success:

```
TASK [drop into tmux and run gunicorn]
*****************************************
    changed: [44.197.228.14] => {"changed": true, "cmd": "tmux has-session -t api || tmux new-session -d -s api /home/akarpov/.local/share/virtualenvs/htmshop_parent-NXHiij2E/bin/gunicorn backend.wsgi:application -b 127.0.0.1:4000", "delta": "0:00:00.012161", "end": "2021-08-25 14:47:14.284544", "rc": 0, "start": "2021-08-25 14:47:14.272383", "stderr": "no server running on /tmp/tmux-0/default", "stderr_lines": ["no server running on /tmp/tmux-0/default"], "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}
```

tmux reporting no server is running error, is what has-session is expected to do; then the second clause of || kicks in... at least it **does** when I run this command manually on the box. But playbook surprises me; the process (gunicorn) is indeed launched (why two? beats me!):

```
> pgrep -a guni
    6542 /home/akarpov/.local/share/virtualenvs/htmshop_parent-NXHiij2E/bin/python /home/akarpov/.local/share/virtualenvs/htmshop_parent-NXHiij2E/bin/gunicorn backend.wsgi:application -b 127.0.0.1:4000
    6548 /home/akarpov/.local/share/virtualenvs/htmshop_parent-NXHiij2E/bin/python /home/akarpov/.local/share/virtualenvs/htmshop_parent-NXHiij2E/bin/gunicorn backend.wsgi:application -b 127.0.0.1:4000
```

but *tmux ls* tells me **no server running on /tmp/tmux-1001/default**

Interestingly enough, if I take a look at processes like this:

```
± |staging ?:13 ✗| → ps auxw | grep guni
root        6541  0.0  0.3   7536  3616 ?        Ss   15:14   0:00 tmux new-session -d -s api /home/akarpov/.local/share/virtualenvs/htmshop_parent-NXHiij2E/bin/gunicorn backend.wsgi:application -b 127.0.0.1:4000
root        6542  0.0  2.2  30352 22340 pts/2    Ss+  15:14   0:00 /home/akarpov/.local/share/virtualenvs/htmshop_parent-NXHiij2E/bin/python /home/akarpov/.local/share/virtualenvs/htmshop_parent-NXHiij2E/bin/gunicorn backend.wsgi:application -b 127.0.0.1:4000
root        6548  0.0  4.1  52532 41984 pts/2    S+   15:14   0:00 /home/akarpov/.local/share/virtualenvs/htmshop_parent-NXHiij2E/bin/python /home/akarpov/.local/share/virtualenvs/htmshop_parent-NXHiij2E/bin/gunicorn backend.wsgi:application -b 127.0.0.1:4000
```

, I do see the tmux (parent process) also... but where's the session? And in what magical subshell-like thing was this pony started, if not in a tmux session? Or perhaps it is a tmux session of some sort, just not one that my tmux knows about?  ¯_(ツ)_/¯

Thank y'all for your time...

Comment: Hm. The session is just an internal data structure in the server. `tmux` should have exited immediately; I'm not sure why it didn't. The server is probably running on a different socket than what your manual `tmux` tries to connect to; was it started by a different user? Check for any other `/tmp/tmux-*` directories.

Comment: For a reproducible deployment, you might want to specify the socket to use explicitly, using `-L` or `-S` options to `tmux`, or the `TMUX_TMPDIR` environment variable.

Comment: `gunicorn` is running using the pseudoterminal `pts/2`, which is managed by the `tmux` server (as part of the `api` session), rather than being managed by your terminal emulator.

Comment: `gnunicorn` probably forks itself for some reason.

Comment: thanks for keeping working with me mate!
your comments though - do they pertain to me running the command manually on the box (which does create a tmux session) or when it's executed through ansible (which doesn't create a session, but does run _two_ gunicorns lol)

Comment: not sure I understand why you call sessions "internal data structure". All tmux cheatsheets and docs I skimmed through talk about them as first-class citizens; attaching to them, and detaching, seems to be the main thing users are expected to do...

Comment: When you run `tmux foo ...`, you are just sending a command to the server to execute. Part of that might involve some other "local" work, for example, `tmux attach-session ...` creates a client that attaches to a specific session managed by the server.

Comment: A session is a collection of pseudoterminals. Access to those pseudoterminals is mediated via the windows (and its constituent panes) linked to the session. The session has a concept of the *active* window, which is what your client first displays when attaching to the session.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not really an answer, but fleshing out some background as to how `tmux` works.

When you run `tmux`, it tries to connect to (or create if necessary) a server running on a particular Unix socket. By default, the path to that socket is something like `/tmp/tmux-$USERID/default`. You can change the directory using the `-L` option or the `TMUX_TMPDIR` environment variable. You can ignore both those using `-S` to specify an exact path your self.

For example,

```
$ tmux -L ~/foo ...   # Talks to a server via ~/foo/default
$ tmux -S ~/foo/bar   # Talks to a server via ~/foo/bar
```

Your playbook is probably executed under a different user ID than your interactive shell, so `tmux` is attempting to communicate with two different servers in that case. I would recommend being explicit in your playbook so that there is no doubt about which server Ansible will create/talk to. Something like

```
- name: Gunicorn in tmux
  environment:
    TMUX_TMPDIR: /tmp/my/ansible/tmux/session
  tasks:
    - name: drop into tmux and run gunicorn
      shell:
        cmd: tmux has-session -t api || tmux new-session -d -s api /home/akarpov/.local/share/virtualenvs/htmshop_parent-NXHiij2E/bin/gunicorn backend.wsgi:application -b 127.0.0.1:4000
        chdir: htmshop_parent
```

I'm somewhat surprised to see that `tmux new-session -d` is still running`, as it should have exited immediately after creating the session (or rather, asking the server to create the session). The` gunicorn`processes are indeed running in this session. When a session is created, a new window for the session is created as well, and according to your output, this window is associated with the pseudoterminal`/dev/pts/2`.

If you were to later try to attach to this session, the command `tmux attach-session -t api` would send a request to the server, asking it (very roughly speaking) which pseudoterminal is associated with the currently active window of the named session. The `tmux` client will then communicate with that pseudoterminal, providing a kind of thin terminal emulation.

So aside from `tmux new-session ...` continuing to run in the background, everything looks like it should.

Comment: got to say, you put much more emphasis on what tmux _really_ is than most, if not all, online search results. guess they hide the real things (server and windows) behind sessions, making folks like me to think they're first class... while they're a user interface artifact, eh

Comment: I hope any of this helps solve your problem :)

Comment: "Your playbook is probably executed under a different user ID than your interactive shell, so tmux is attempting to communicate with two different servers in that case." -
oh man, that's exactly it. what a noob mistake; playbook is indeed ran as root - and dropping to root on the box I see my session, no magic, just bloody linux basics...